# Conditional operator in js

Tags: javascript, comparison

I know the usage of conditional operator with question mark.

```
var number = 5;
return number === 5 ? true : false;
```

What I'm asking is this; 
Is it possible to assign multiple values in conditional operator? Like this;

```
var age, grade;
(number === 5) ? (age = 21, grade = 2) : (age = 22, grade = 3)
```

Comment: yes you can do multiple assignments

Comment: put your assignments into objects

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like,

```
var [age, grade] = (number === 5) ? [21, 2] : [22, 3]
```

**Example**

```
> number = 2
> var [age, grade ] = (number === 5) ? [21, 2] : [ 22, 3 ]
> age
< 22
> grade
< 3
```

Comment: Thank you but when I tried to run I get "'destructuring expression' is only available in JavaScript 1.7."

Comment: Tested fine on Chrome 50

Answer (score 0):

That is valid javascript, what you had

```js
var number = 5, age, grade;

number === 5 ? (age = 21, grade = 2) : (age = 22, grade = 3);

console.log(age);
console.log(grade);
```

Comment: I get "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."  when I try in the .call

Comment: on which user agent?

Comment: Interesting I am using Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36 too.

Comment: @YigitCan what `.call` are you referring to? You have not provided that segment of your code.